# Posit R Studio crashes when I load data frames

Tags: r, rstudio

I have been working with a data set from Kaggle - the Cyclistic data set. Here's a link...https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/johnp47/cyclistic-2021-dataset

Anyway, the problem I have is when I try to load the .csv files for the last 12 monthhankss, Posit R Studio can't handle it and crashes.
The only thing I did was clean the datafields in R and delete all the rows with null values. Other than that, its pretty much the same as the original .csv files.

I will try to email support at Posit but just in case, does anyone out there have a solution or has this happened to you?

Thanks Fellow Travelers.

tried loading the .csv files over and over to bind the rows. I tried with a single command line and with separate commands for each month (12 total).
Both of these crash the R Studio.

The csv files will load separately. One at a time.
However, when I get to around 9 to 10 in memory, the system crashes.

Note, I have changed my subscription to the annual primo one, hoping this would give me more memory and no crashes but....alas....it still crashed.

My goal was just to bind the rows and make one big file. These are big files themselves but this is not unheard of and shouldn't be a problem for R Studio.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: More likely that you are maxing out your memory. You could eliminate Posit as cause by running in regular R.

Comment: I was able to load in the files with on that site and merge them without a problem. I agree it is more likely to be a memory limitation than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured this out. I had to restart it a few times. R Studio has a resources allocation area. I ended up having to push it to the max.

I also saved more and backed up more. So when it did crash, I was able to recover.

In the end, I just took image files from the analysis and put it on a nice RMD file.
Lessons learned.