# Repeated RStudio crashes about 1 minute after using it

Tags: r, crash, rstudio

I am experiencing repeated RStudio crashes about 1 minute after using it and uploading my .RData. I am using `Windows 11`. I updated to the latest version of `RStudio` in a trial to solve that and here are the details when I open it:

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt) -- "Eye Holes"
Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Workspace loaded from ~/.RData]
```

[image]

Here are my `session.info()`

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] rstudioapi_0.14         jsonlite_1.8.4          shape_1.4.6             magrittr_2.0.3          TH.data_1.1-2          
  [6] estimability_1.4.1      jomo_2.7-6              nloptr_2.0.3            rmarkdown_2.25          fs_1.6.2               
 [11] ragg_1.2.5              vctrs_0.6.2             sjPlot_2.8.14           memoise_2.0.1           minqa_1.2.5            
 [16] askpass_1.1             webshot_0.5.5           forcats_1.0.0           htmltools_0.5.7         haven_2.5.2            
 [21] curl_5.0.0              truncnorm_1.0-9         broom_1.0.4             gridGraphics_0.5-1      sjmisc_2.8.9           
 [26] mitml_0.4-5             parallelly_1.35.0       forestmodel_0.6.2       sandwich_3.0-2          zoo_1.8-12             
 [31] emmeans_1.8.8           cachem_1.0.7            uuid_1.1-0              mime_0.12               lifecycle_1.0.4        
 [36] iterators_1.0.14        pkgconfig_2.0.3         sjlabelled_1.2.0        Matrix_1.6-1.1          R6_2.5.1               
 [41] fastmap_1.1.1           future_1.32.0           shiny_1.7.4             digest_0.6.31           aplot_0.2.2            
 [46] colorspace_2.1-0        patchwork_1.2.0         chron_2.3-61            textshaping_0.3.6       fansi_1.0.4            
 [51] httr_1.4.5              abind_1.4-5             compiler_4.3.2          ggbreak_0.1.2           fontquiver_0.2.1       
 [56] backports_1.4.1         carData_3.0-5           performance_0.10.3      fastDummies_1.6.3       pan_1.8                
 [61] MASS_7.3-60             lava_1.7.2.1            openssl_2.0.6           sjstats_0.18.2          gfonts_0.2.0           
 [66] tools_4.3.2             zip_2.3.0               httpuv_1.6.9            future.apply_1.10.0     nnet_7.3-19            
 [71] glue_1.6.2              nlme_3.1-163            promises_1.2.0.1        grid_4.3.2              generics_0.1.3         
 [76] gtable_0.3.3            labelled_2.11.0         tidyr_1.3.0             hms_1.1.3               data.table_1.14.8      
 [81] xml2_1.3.4              car_3.1-2               utf8_1.2.3              compareGroups_4.7.0     foreach_1.5.2          
 [86] pillar_1.9.0            stringr_1.5.1           yulab.utils_0.1.4       later_1.3.0             splines_4.3.2          
 [91] dplyr_1.1.2             lattice_0.21-9          survival_3.5-7          tidyselect_1.2.0        fontLiberation_0.1.0   
 [96] HardyWeinberg_1.7.5     knitr_1.45              fontBitstreamVera_0.1.1 svglite_2.1.1           crul_1.3               
[101] xfun_0.39               Publish_2023.01.17      Rsolnp_1.16             stringi_1.7.12          ggfun_0.1.4            
[106] yaml_2.3.7              boot_1.3-28.1           kableExtra_1.3.4        evaluate_0.23           codetools_0.2-19       
[111] httpcode_0.3.0          officer_0.6.2           gdtools_0.3.3           tibble_3.2.1            ggplotify_0.1.2        
[116] cli_3.6.1               rpart_4.1.21            xtable_1.8-4            systemfonts_1.0.4       munsell_0.5.0          
[121] modelr_0.1.11           Rcpp_1.0.10             globals_0.16.2          ggeffects_1.2.1         coda_0.19-4            
[126] parallel_4.3.2          ellipsis_0.3.2          ggplot2_3.4.2           bayestestR_0.13.1       lme4_1.1-33            
[131] listenv_0.9.0           glmnet_4.1-7            mvtnorm_1.1-3           viridisLite_0.4.2       scales_1.2.1           
[136] prodlim_2023.03.31      insight_0.19.1          purrr_1.0.1             crayon_1.5.2            writexl_1.4.2          
[141] flextable_0.9.2         rlang_1.1.1             multcomp_1.4-23         rvest_1.0.3             mice_3.16.0
```

I checked prior [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75976135/posit-r-studio-crashes-when-i-load-data-frames) [but](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-keeps-crashing/165228) I couldn't solve it yet.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose the problem only occurs when you load the .RData file it isn't? so what happen if you Session > clear workspace then restart session ?

Comment: @Ric Thanks a lot. I restarted my laptop and did what you said. Now, it works perfectly. Appreciate your help. Upvoted.